# Skype a-like PlugIn

Tags: ms-office, plugins, skype

This is not really a programming question but please bear with me as I just need some push to the right road.

What is and what should I search for to create a Skype A-Like plugin?

I want to be able to **capture the Phone Number** (Web Browser, Word and Outlook for starts) and change it to present a link that the user can click to **search that Phone Number in the CRM** Application, given him the ability to open that client profile or make a call (we have a PBX Dial software).

But I have **no idea what this technology is called** in order to start looking for some ideas on how to accomplish this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For Office: **[Shared Add-in](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/addin_office_using_csharp.aspx?msg=1313321)**
- For Internet Explorer: **[BHO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250489%28VS.85%29.aspx)** (Browser Helper Object)
- For Firefox: **[Extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Building_an_Extension)**